# Delta Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

[image]Below Delta Graph API is returning all results for changes on Users. How can I retrieve only changed data from Azure AD?

Could anyone help me with this?

```
var result = await graphClient.Users.Delta.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
      requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "displayName","givenName","surname" };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I remember, the first call to delta always returns all data. You will need to store OdataDeltaLink and use it later to get new changes

```
var result = await graphClient.Users.Delta.GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName", "givenName", "surname" };
});

// read @odata.deltaLink
var deltaLink = result.OdataDeltaLink;

// SDK doesn't expose any query parameter to directly set deltalink
var nextResponse = await graphClient.Users.Delta.WithUrl($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltatoken={deltaLink}").GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync();
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but I am getting a null value from OdataDeltaLink.

Comment: there should be another property like nextlink or something like that. Is it also null?

Comment: If you see the results attached here, I used the OdataNext Link and it is providing all the results.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? Please share.